# how to redirect to react js application using node js, in same server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have two different react js Application, and i want to redirect the user to the application depending on the url

example :

```
app.get('/' , (req,res,next) => {
  // redirect to first SPA
});

app.get('/admin' , (req,res,next) => {
  // redirect to another SPA
});
```

Comment: You can try Location header in response.

Comment: Need to change the order of those then send appropriate html file

Comment: @estus the spa runs on 127.0.0.1:3006

Comment: I'd suggest to do this at web server level, Nginx or whatever you have. This isn't a very good use for app server, which Node is.

Comment: @estus thanks for response, but the problem here that i need authentification, it's so complicated

Comment: Your case is quite typical. I don't see the problem with auth here. Usually it's beneficial to route admin to different subdomain, makes everything more straightforward and sometimes more secure.

Comment: @estus The problem here, is  the profile of a user need to be a dashboard like the admin one, so another  react js application.

Comment: I don't see the problem with that. If auth works right now, it will work then. You mount one SPA (e.g. 127.0.0.1:3005) to /admin. You mount another SPA (e.g. 127.0.0.1:3006) to / . This can be achieved with either web server or Node, but the former is much more efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999688/forward-express-js-route-to-other-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the react app is to be served from the node.js server, simply send each app's `index.html`:

```
app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('admin_app/index.html');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public_app/index.html');
});
```

If those files are served from a different process on the same machine you will have to proxy the requests:

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxy = httpProxy.createServer({});

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3006/admin' });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3006/' });
});
```

Redirects would also work, as long as the process at `127.0.0.1:3006` listens on all public addresses. But a redirect includes that the users browser navigates to a different URL. E.g. if your node.js server was running at `example.com` (i.e. port 80, which the browser omits) and redirects to the other process, the browser would now show `example.com:3006`. By proxying the request, the URL will stay on `example.com`.

Comment: the problem is, that i get a blank page, i was redirected to my react application.

Comment: Is it actually blank, i.e. no content sent, or just a white page because nothing can be rendered (e.g. due to js files not being loaded)? Did you check the console in your browsers developer tools for errors? Do you get any content when loading the URL with `curl`?

Comment: all the page is rendred, but only html can be showed, that works with redirect, but not with proxy, i have a blank page.

Comment: If all static content is hosted at `localhost:3006` you will to redirect/proxy more that just those two paths. My answer was mostly about giving an idea how it can be done. What/How much has to be redirected depends a lot on your specific set up and on the applications.

Comment: Hey @LucasS. well i am able to redirect to localhost:3000 without using proxy so exactly what is use of proxy i just did res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/surveys') ofcos in my project but everything seems fine

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai I explained that briefly in the last paragraph. Both approaches will work fine. The only difference is which port the browser is sending requests to.
In the case of redirects, the browser sends requests to ports other than `80` (or `443` for HTTPS). The browser's address bar will then show these ports (e.g. `http://example.com:3000/surveys`). Users are not used to this, so I wouldn't recommend it for any public-facing system.
When proxying the requests, the port doesn't change (`http://example.com/surveys`).

Answer (score 0):

How about in a route middleware, `res.redirect('http://someOtherServer/`?

Such as `res.redirect('http://localhost:5000')`.

Maybe this other answer will help [Nodejs - Redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)